# How to use global variable safely in dlopen-ed shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, elf, dlopen

One of my project for Linux uses a lot of shared libraries which are connected with `dlopen/dlsym/dlclose` to gain modularity. For thread-safety reason, I need to put global variable (`boost::mutex`) in one of shared library. Obviously, `boost::mutex` has [non-trivial destructor](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/377bb87ad5875ddf357cbcf8aee51659d979f916/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp#L103). (it can even `abort(3)` the program).

I understand that using global variable that are not trivially destructible is bad idea and some guidelines are explicitly [forbid](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/63107a12eb85a4da33e2585a912234e4794cea06/cppguide.html#L853) to do such things, but I really need global mutex for the module.

After adding global `boost::mutex` variable, it crashes on program exit. (`boost::mutex::lock()` throws because of `EINVAL` of `pthread_mutex_lock`) I assume that the shared libary called after main, but, that mutex is already destroyed. (static destruction order fiasco things, I assume.)

Unfortunately, this program is quite complicated and I need a workaround to do my job on time.
After digging ctor/dtor things, I found that this code works.

```
#include <boost/aligned_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/alignment_of.hpp>

boost::aligned_storage<sizeof(boost::mutex), boost::alignment_of<boost::mutex>::value> gMutexStorage;
boost::mutex* gMutex = NULL;

__attribute__ ((constructor))
void MyModuleInit()
{
    gMutex = new(reinterpret_cast<boost::mutex*>(gMutexStorage.address())) boost::mutex();
}

__attribute__ ((destructor))
void MyModuleUnInit()
{
    gMutex->~mutex();
    gMutex = NULL;
}

// global mutex use
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
int SomeFunc(...)
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(*gMutex);
    ....
}
```

Then, this `MyModuleUnInit` function registered in `.fini_array` section (For the reference, other destructor of static C++ variable registered in `__cxa_atexit`) of the shared library and it is called after mutex use, so program exits normally.

However, I am not confident of the safety of that mutex usage. Are these code is Okay to use? If not, how can I deal with static(global) variable for dlopen-ed shared library?

Comment: "*I really need global mutex for the module*" No, you don't. You need a globally *accessible* mutex, but there's nothing that says you have to expose a genuine global *variable* to have such a thing.

Comment: I wish I could remove whole global variable and let the user of the shared library construct/destruct their own variable, but there is an ABI constraint, so I cannot change the interface easily.

Comment: What kind of ABI requires boost::mutex?

Comment: Also, all shared libraries are built with `-fvisibility=hidden` and, internal linkage of global variables (`namespace {}`) does not make a difference.

Comment: I think are supposed to use `init_priority` for C++ nowadays. `init_priority` allows you to assign a priority for construction (order object construction across translation units). `__attribute__ ((constructor))` is deprecated. A search should turn up a discussion about it, like on the GCC or Binutils mailing list. Also, if you can, just use C++11 dynamic initialization. Get rid of the global C++ objects altogether. They are more trouble than they are worth (speaking from experience as a maintainer of an open source c++ lib).